# How i can substract and sum results all arrays in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have a few arrays in array :

```
([[10,0],[3,5],[5,8]])
```

I try substract all inner arrays a - b and then sum results ( example : 10 - 0 = 10, 3-5 = -2, 5-8 = -3, 10+(-2)+(-3) = 5;

My try:

```
 var el;
 return array.reduce((a, b) => a - b );
```

But my result came out Nan, now Im understood, in my code i want substring array from array - bad idea.
I know how do this with using `for` or something like that, my question is:

how i can do this with use `reduce` or other ''modern'' method?

Thanks for help.

PS sorry for my English skill ;)

Comment: looks like a usual problem ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337579/how-i-can-substract-and-sum-results-all-arrays-in-array

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce()` method like this.

```js
var data = [[10,0],[3,5],[5,8]]
var result = data.reduce((r, e) => r + (e[0] - e[1]), 0);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexible solution, the size of the nested arrays doesn't matter, it will still return a proper result.

```js
const count = (arr) => arr.reduce((s, v) => {
        s += v.reduce((a,b) => a - b);
        return s;
      }, 0);

let arr1 = [ [10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8] ],
    arr2 = [ [5, 4, 1], [3, 5, 5], [5, 8] ];
    
console.log(count(arr1));
console.log(count(arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You were close, but be sure to have an initial value of `0` and dereference the inner arrays into `a` and `b` like so:

```js
var array = [[10,0],[3,5],[5,8]];

var result = array.reduce((prev, [a, b]) => prev + (a - b), 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ([[10,8],[3,5],[5,8]]);
arr.map(pair => pair[0] - pair[1]).reduce((a,b) => a + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the outer and inner arrays.

```js
var array = [[10, 0], [3, 5], [5, 8]],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + a.reduce(function (x, y) {
            return x - y;
        })
    }, 0);

console.log(result);
```